# Docker .withRun() command errors out

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubectl

I am trying to change the user to uid to 0

```
docker.image('pahud/eks-kubectl-docker').withRun('-u 0:0').inside.{
          withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
                        credentialsId: awsCredentialsId,
                        accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',  
                        secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']])

            {
           sh 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2  CLUSTER_NAME=oeksctl'

      sh 'aws eks --region us-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name eksctl'
```

I am getting the following error

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.withRun() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [-u 0:0]
Possible solutions: with(groovy.lang.Closure), withTool(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1501)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1487)
```

Comment: Try using `.withRun('-u 0:0') {` instead of `.withRun('-u 0:0').inside.{`

Answer (score 1):

this should be like this

```
docker.image('pahud/eks-kubectl-docker').inside('-u 0:0'){
```

instead of

```
docker.image('pahud/eks-kubectl-docker').withRun('-u 0:0').inside{
```